# Set srid in GeoDjango - GeometryField raises NotImplementError

Tags: django, django-models, geodjango

I want to set `srid=5179`, not the default `4326`. Thus I write it like this:

```
area=models.GeometryField(blank=True, null=True, srid=5179)
```

Migrating the model works very well, but when I use this model Django raises an Exception with the message:

```
NotImplementedError: This backend doesn't support the Transform function.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Which DBMS (database) do you use? PostgreSQL with PostGIS? Or something else? Please provide more information.

Comment: using mysql that support geojson(geometry field) version

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/functions/) say (in the first paragraph after the example) that not all databases support the functions you need

> If you call a geographic function on a backend that doesn’t support it, you’ll get a NotImplementedError exception.